# error middleware in azure-mobile-apps-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, error-handling, azure-mobile-services

I want to catch errors from **api** folder.

However, the express error handling middleware catch nothing unless the errors triggered from any handler declared using standard express routing `app.get(someroute,handler)`

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks in advance.

**app.js**

```
mobile.api.import('./api');
mobile.tables.initialize()
    .then(function () {
        app.use(mobile);    // Register the Azure Mobile Apps middleware
        app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);   // Listen for requests
    })
    .then(function(){
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'){
            ///handle errors on prod
            app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
                console.log('error catch - here');
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.end();
            });
        }
    });
```

**api/testing.js**

```
module.exports = {
    "get": function (req, res, next) {
        throw new Error('this is error');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.  The Node.js SDK for Azure Mobile Apps uses Express, so it uses the same semantics.  (Side note - we briefly discussed not implementing a custom API facility.  It's really there to support the in-portal editing capability of the Azure portal).

A better question (and one not for this forum, which is about answering programming questions) is what do you want to happen?  File an issue on the https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node repository so we can have that discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `mobile.use(function (err, req, res, next) { /* ... */ })` after `mobile.api.import`. This will mount the error handling middleware before the azure-mobile-apps error handler.